# Solving the differential equation with given condition on coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be nonzero real numbers such that $(a-b)^2= 4ac$. Solve the differential equation $$ a(x- \sqrt 2)^2y''+ b(x-\sqrt 2)y'+ cy=0.$$

How can I use the given condition here? Or should I go for Frobenius series solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x-\sqrt{2}=t$, then ODE is
$$at^2y''+bty'+cy=0$$Here ' means derivative w.r.t. $t$.
This Euler's ODE, let $y=t^m$ to get $$a m(m-1)+bm+c=0 \implies m_1,m_2=\frac{(a-b)\pm \sqrt{(b-a)^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ So the dolution 
$$y=C_1 t^{m_1} + C_2 t^{m_2} \implies y=C_1(x-\sqrt{2})^{m_1}+ C_2 (x-\sqrt{2})^{m_2}$$

But since $m_1=m_2=(a-b)/(2a)$, the solution is given by
$$y=(C_1 \ln t+ C_2)t^{m} \implies  y=[C_1 \ln(x-\sqrt{2}+C_2] (x-\sqrt{2})^m.$$